# Getting Wrong Post ID Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I have problem with getting the wrong Post id, or either the half of it. 
So I have a function which is posting status to facebook:

```
$objRequest = $this->objFB->post($strURL, $arrOptions);
```

And when I `var_dump($objRequest)` I get an ID like the following:

> "1327463273983745_1402929956437076"

But when I try to access that Post id via Graph API, it says it doesn't exist. Also I have tried to decode `$objRequest` before var_dumping it, but I get the same result.

The correct id of this post is (I find out it through Graph API):

> "865232380206839_1402929956437076"

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: Are you posting as a user, or as a page? If as a user - do you have permission from the user to read their posts?

Comment: I am posting as a user on my own feed. I have all premission needed.

Comment: One of the “prefixes” is your app-scoped user id, I presume - what is the other one? Does it lead to the same user object?

Comment: I don't understand the first part of ID but I can see that the second part is the same. So with get request I get "1327463273983745_1402929956437076"
Instead of 
"865232380206839_1402929956437076"

Comment: @CBroe , The first part is my own ID, and the second part should be the post id. But the post ID is connected with userID so it should be like

userID_postID

But for some reason, I get this 13274632... And I am wondering why. And how can I handle this sort of problem.
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: No, I meant what the two first parts refer to - `1327463273983745` and `865232380206839`

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Make an API request for those two ids, and see what you get.

Comment: I already did that. For this first one I get
"    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1327463273983745' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation."

And if I create another post, this first part is always the same, for some reason.

If I request for the second one(865232380206839) I only get my own id(user_id)

Comment: facebook.com/1327463273983745 and facebook.com/865232380206839 both redirect to your user profile. So it looks like it might be a mix-up with app-scoped vs global user ids, or something like that.

Comment: Since I can request data for 865232380206839 via API, I assume that is your global user id. But you should be able to read data for 1327463273983745 as well, if that is your app-scoped user id, and not get unsupported GET request ... are you sure you used an access token that belongs to your app id?

Comment: If I type in url "facebook.com/1327463273983745/" it redirects me to my user page. But when I do so in Graph API, i get
"    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1327463273983745' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","

Comment: Yes, I know, that is the standard message for content you are not allowed to see. Did you use a user access token belonging to your app for that request?

Comment: Yes sir, I did.